# clientprotocolexception DefaultHttpClient.execute()

Tags: android, httpclient

I am using the following code to request a response from a webserver. The server sends a malformed response without headers  which causes a ClientProtocolException. I have tried to use inspectors but they are not called before the exception is fired. I cannot change the server (it is within an embedded device, ALFA router R36).
Any suggestions to deal with this problem (btw: the code works perfect if the server response is well-formed)

Thanks in advance, Ton

```
class httpRequestTask extends AsyncTask <Integer, Integer, Integer> {

    StringBuffer respTxt = new StringBuffer("");        
    int reqCode = 0;


    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... requestCode) {
        Integer reqStatus = 0;
        String url = "http://192.168.2.1/";
        String authString = ("admin:admin");

        switch( reqCode = requestCode[0].intValue()){
            case Constants.HTTP_GET_STATUS_INFO:    url += "/adm/status_info.asp";              break;
            case Constants.HTTP_SCAN:               url += "/goform/getUsbStaBSSIDListForm";    break;
        }

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            HttpResponse response;

            request.setURI( new URI( url));           
            request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(authString.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));

            response = client.execute(request);
            reqStatus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            String line;
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) respTxt.append(line);
        } catch ( ClientProtocolException e){
            Log.e("ALFA", "HTTPReq:ClientProtocolException " + e.toString());
        } catch ( IOException e){
            Log.e("ALFA", "HTTPReq:IOException " + e.toString());
        } catch ( Exception e){
            Log.e("ALFA", "HTTPReq:Exception " + e.toString());
        }

        return reqStatus;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer reqStatus) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.HTTP_RESPONSE);

        intent.putExtra( "reqCode", reqCode);
        intent.putExtra( "reqStatus", reqStatus);
        intent.putExtra( "rspTxt", respTxt.toString());

        getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: i would try another library like http://square.github.io/okhttp/, and see if it handles it differently. or better lets me handle the case manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking further to find a solution to the problem I found a suggestion to use a socket to request the server.  I used [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) in combination with a browser on my PC to examine the data send to and received from the buggy server and read an article on Wikipedia, explaining the HTTP protocol. With that info and by using a Socket, I wrote a very basic httpRequestHandler than deals with the miss formed response from the buggy web server.

```
class httpSocketRequest extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
    StringBuffer respTxt = new StringBuffer("");        
    int reqCode = 0;
    int reqStatus = 0;

    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... requestCode) {
        String ip = "192.168.2.1";
        String path = "";
        String authString = ("admin:admin");
        Socket socket = null;

        switch( reqCode = requestCode[0].intValue()){
            case Constants.HTTP_GET_STATUS_INFO:    path = "adm/status_info.asp";               break;
            case Constants.HTTP_SCAN:               path = "goform/getUsbStaBSSIDListForm";     break;
        }

        try {
            socket = new Socket( ip, 80);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream());
            out.println( "GET http://" + ip + "/" + path + " HTTP/1.0");
            out.println( "Authorization: Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(authString.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
            out.println( "");
            out.flush();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            int lineCnt = 0;

            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                if( lineCnt >= 0){
                    lineCnt++;
                    if(lineCnt == 1){           // first line should start with "HTTP/1.x " followed by a 3 digit status
                        if( line.length() > 12 && line.substring(0, 6).equals("HTTP/1")){
                            int p = line.indexOf(" ");
                            reqStatus = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(p+1, p+4));
                            continue;
                        } else {                // not a well formed response
                            lineCnt = -1;       // just put everything into respTxt
                            reqStatus = 200;    // and assume everything went OK
                        }
                    } else if( lineCnt > 1){    // process rest of headers
                        if( line.length() == 0){
                            lineCnt = -1;       // done with headers
                        } else {
                            // TODO insert code to process other headers
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                respTxt.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ALFA", "HTTPReq:Exception " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                if( socket != null) socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ALFA", "HTTPReq:Exception closing socket" + e.toString());
            }
        }

        return reqStatus;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer reqStatus) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.HTTP_RESPONSE);

        intent.putExtra( "reqCode", reqCode);
        intent.putExtra( "reqStatus", reqStatus);
        intent.putExtra( "rspTxt", respTxt.toString());

        getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```